# How to use microsoft isa proxy with authentication on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, proxy, authentication

my apt.conf file:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@server:port/";    
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@server:port/";    
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@server:port/";
```

my enviroment file:

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@server:port
export https_proxy=http://user:password@server:port
export ftp_proxy=http://user:password@server:port
```

error:

```
vinicius@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease   
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease  
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg          
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg  
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release              
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release      
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                  
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources             
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages      
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages       
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-pt_BR   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-pt      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en      
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources  
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-pt
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-pt
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-pt
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-pt
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-pt_BR
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-pt
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

W: Falhou ao buscar http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( O ISA Server exige autorização para preencher a solicitação. Acesso ao filtro de Proxy da Web negado.  )

E: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you still don't authenticate properly.
There may be a number of reasons for that - like special characters in your password, where it may be better to replace them by their code, I think.

If you have windows proxy server - cntlm might help.
I think actually that if you use package manager and give credentials there in the config - it might also work. Or in System config - and try to update in the gui, to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with this program: [microsoft-isa-proxy-authentication](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.pt/2012/10/microsoft-isa-proxy-authentication-in.html)

Microsoft ISA Proxy authentication in Ubuntu
How to solve "407 Proxy Authentication Required" error in Ubuntu ?
This was one question I was behind from last few days. Use CNTLM, that's the best answer I got.
CNTLM will make your Ubuntu server act as a proxy server and in behind authenticates with your actual proxy server.

1. Download the package file from the CNTLM website. While writing this, [version 0.92.3](http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cntlm/cntlm/cntlm%200.92.3/cntlm_0.92.3_i386.deb) is the latest.
2. Install `.deb` file, e. g.:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cntlm_0.92.3_i386.deb
   ```
3. The CNTLM configuration file is located at `/etc/cntlm.conf`. Open it using your preferred text editor in edit mode. If you use gedit, type `sudo gedit /etc/cntlm.conf`.
4. In `cntlm.conf` edit the following fields:

   ```
   Username   YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
   Domain     YOUR_ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN
   Password YOUR_PASSWORD
   Proxy  YOUR_PROXY_SERVER_IP_WITH_PORT
   NoProxy LIST_ALL_IP_WITH_NO_PROXY_REQUIREMENT
   Listen SOME_PORT
   ```

   Sample config here:

   ```
   Username   0906895
   Domain     ABC
   Password   rndmpasswd@123
   Proxy  10.18.200.203:8080
   Proxy  10.18.200.204:8080
   NoProxy  localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*
   Listen  8080
   ```
5. After changes in configuration files, restart the CNTLM service:

   ```
   sudo service cntlm restart
   ```
6. Now CNTLM started working and your Ubuntu server is acting as another proxy server. So add `localhost` as the system proxy server:

   Go to System -> Preference -> Network Proxy. In the Network Proxy Preference window, set manual proxy configuration, proxy server as `localhost` and port as the port number you specified in `Listen SOME_PORT`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster and now?